# Display image in original size in Finder's preview column

Tags: macos, finder, preview

Is there a way to see the image in the preview column of the Finder in original size?

Right now the images are stretched to fill the entire width of the column, even if the image is just a small 32x32px icon.

This happens in all View modes of the Finder: as Icons, as Columns.

[image: click to view large size]

In Windows 7 if you have opened a folder with small images, then it attempts to keep their original size, so you can have a better view of how that file looks.

Here is a screenshot OS X (left) vs. Windows 7 (right):

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, that is the "Get Info" window and not the preview. The preview is separate application in os x.

Comment: The Get info window is scalable to some level that will also increase the image size, but not to the original size.

Comment: I was very clear specifying that it happens in the PREVIEW COLUMN of the FINDER, not in the Preview app or in the Get Info window. I simply included the "Get Info" window in the first screenshot so you can see that in other places the image size is fine.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong.

Comment: I have the same frustration. This is still broken (as it makes no sense stretching an image to fill the width of the preview pane) as of Sep 2018 / MacOS High Sierra...